# Where does Hegel say the following?

Tags: hegel

Where does Hegel say the following or something like it?

> Our universities . . . are our churches.

Comment: The following search got several hits: Hegel, “our universities are our churches “.

Comment: @MarkAndrews I couldn’t find the quote that way. I would appreciate a link if you have found.

Comment: https://epdf.pub/protestant-theology-and-the-making-of-the-modern-german-university.html

Answer (score 3):

Encyclopedia of Philosophical Sciences, vol.3 (Philosophy of Spirit), "Presentation" // GW p.34

Comment: Could you please mention the exact quotation and a like to it online maybe?